# How can I restore a weird Windows backup?

Tags: backup, zip, windows-backup

I need to restore some files that I saved about 5 years ago. Back then I created a backup with Windows, but I don't remember how or which Windows Version it was. All I have now are the files from the backup. Maybe somebody can help tell me what type of Backup it is and how I can restore it?

The backup is in a folder called 506122934. The folder structure looks like this:

```
506122934
->150424
-->Program Files
--->More Folders
-->Windows
--->More Folders
-->User
--->Default
--->Public
--->Me
---->Myfile1
---->Myfile2
->150424_data
-->transaction
--->00000002345
---->content
---->context.bin
---->hash
---->header
---->trace
--->00000002346
---->content
---->context.bin
---->hash
---->header
---->trace
-->content
-->hash
-->trace
->history
```

That means my original system folder structure was mirrored and I can actually navigate to the files I want to restore. Unfortunately, all the files are stored in some binary format. Even if I open a text file, all I get is something like this:

```
504b 0304 2d00 0808 0800 56b5 9846 0000
0000 ffff ffff ffff ffff 0d00 0000 4433
4439 5072 6f78 792e 6c6f 6773 c92c 4a4d
2e31 7671 2e4a 4d2c 49b5 d430 36d2 e4e5
0200 504b 0708 a82b 9c3b 1700 0000 0000
0000 1500 0000 0000 0000 504b 0102 2d00
2d00 0808 0800 56b5 9846 a82b 9c3b ffff
ffff ffff ffff 0d00 2000 0000 ffff 0000
0000 0000 ffff ffff 4433 4439 5072 6f78
792e 6c6f 6701 001c 0015 0000 0000 0000
0017 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0050 4b06 062c 0000 0000 0000
0014 0014 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000
0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 005b 0000
0000 0000 005a 0000 0000 0000 0050 4b06
0700 0000 00b5 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000
0050 4b05 0600 0000 00ff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ff00 00
```

504b 0304 looks like the header for a zip file, even though this is supposed to be a text file. Maybe the backup software stores all files as zip files?
I tried to select the hard disk in the Windows Backup restore dialog, but it can't find any backups on it. FileHistory also says there are not backups detected.

Any ideas on how to proceed?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing this question, I solved it at least partially. The header looks like a ZIP file and I can open the file in WinRar as a zip file even though the ending is .txt or .pdf. Then I have the real file inside and I can extract that. This gives me a way to restore individual files, although I still don't know how to restore the whole backup.

If you know more, let me know. I am leaving this question up because I think it is helpful for other people.